# How to get the return code of make in a shell script?

Tags: shell, makefile

If I have a shell script which include a 'make' command, which make a C++ project. How can I get the return code of the make command? Just like?

```
RETURN_CODE=`make`
```

Anyone got experience here?

Comment: If `make` was the last thing executed, then, `RETURN_CODE=$?`. What `RETURN_CODE=\`make\`` will do is set `RETURN_CODE` to the output of `make`. See, for example, [Exit and Exit Status](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/exit-status.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [special variable](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Parameters#Special_Parameters_and_Variables) `$?` contains the return code of the last command. You can [save it to a variable](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/002) like this:

```
make
exit_code=$?
```

`` RETURN_CODE=`make` `` is a [command substitution](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/CommandSubstitution), and results in *standard output* of `make` being saved to the variable `RETURN_CODE`.

PS: [You should use `$(foo)` command substitution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/126927/have-backticks-i-e-cmd-in-sh-shells-been-deprecated) rather than backticks, and uppercase variable names are by convention only those which are `export`ed to other scripts.